# How to order (sort) a <li> list with numeric content?

Tags: jquery, list, sorting, html-lists

I have a list as below that is created dynamically:

```html
<ul>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>32</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible order this list using jQuery? I need it ordered from lower to bigger, like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>32</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below should do the trick:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var liContents = [];
    $('ul li').each(function() {
      liContents.push(parseInt($(this).text(), 10));
    });
    liContents.sort(numOrdDesc);
    $('ul li').each(function() {
      $(this).text(liContents.pop());
    });
  });
});

function numOrdDesc(a, b) {
  return (b - a);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>32</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>

<button>Sort</button>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var li = $('ul li');
li.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(parseInt($(a).text()) > parseInt($(b).text()))
        return 1;
    else return -1;
});
$('ul').empty().html(li);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are jQuery plugins to handle this as well.  Check out [TinySort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible way to do it:

```js
$(function() {
  var elems = $('ul').children('li').remove();
  elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt($(a).text()) > parseInt($(b).text());
  });
  $('ul').append(elems);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>32</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
var listItems = [];
$("#list li").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
  listItems.push(parseInt($(this).text()));
});

listItems.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b
});

$("#list").html("");
$.each(listItems, function(i, v) {
  $("#list").append($("<li>" + v + "</li>"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li>20</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>32</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **sortContent** plugin ,everything will be easy,**clean** and ready for reuse :

```
 $('ul').sortContent({helper:myhelper});
```

Known that :

```
myhelper=function(e){
   return $('a',$(e)).attr('href');
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/eVG5p/)

---

If you want to discover other options , visit [Plugin HOMEPAGE](https://github.com/abdennour/jquery.sortContent)

Comment: You should make it clear that you're the author of the plugin you're suggesting.