# Sort HTML list with HTML content using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to sort the list bellow from the lower number to the bigger number, keeping each li content?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        39
        <img class="botao-remover-tamanho" title="Remover cor" alt="" src="/admin/imagens/botao-excluir-cor.png">
        <input type="hidden" title="39" value="39" name="array_variacao[]">
    </li>
    <li>
        34
        <img class="botao-remover-tamanho" title="Remover cor" alt="" src="/admin/imagens/botao-excluir-cor.png">
        <input type="hidden" title="34" value="34" name="array_variacao[]">
    </li>
    <li>
        38
        <img class="botao-remover-tamanho" title="Remover cor" alt="" src="/admin/imagens/botao-excluir-cor.png">
        <input type="hidden" title="38" value="38" name="array_variacao[]">
    </li>
    <li>
        35
        <img class="botao-remover-tamanho" title="Remover cor" alt="" src="/admin/imagens/botao-excluir-cor.png">
        <input type="hidden" title="35" value="35" name="array_variacao[]">
    </li>
    <li>
        33
        <img class="botao-remover-tamanho" title="Remover cor" alt="" src="/admin/imagens/botao-excluir-cor.png">
        <input type="hidden" title="33" value="33" name="array_variacao[]">
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need it ordered like bellow automatically because the list will be created dynamically.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        33
        <img class="botao-remover-tamanho" title="Remover cor" alt="" src="/admin/imagens/botao-excluir-cor.png">
        <input type="hidden" title="33" value="33" name="array_variacao[]">
    </li>
    <li>
        34
        <img class="botao-remover-tamanho" title="Remover cor" alt="" src="/admin/imagens/botao-excluir-cor.png">
        <input type="hidden" title="34" value="34" name="array_variacao[]">
    </li>
    <li>
        35
        <img class="botao-remover-tamanho" title="Remover cor" alt="" src="/admin/imagens/botao-excluir-cor.png">
        <input type="hidden" title="35" value="35" name="array_variacao[]">
    </li>
    <li>
        38
        <img class="botao-remover-tamanho" title="Remover cor" alt="" src="/admin/imagens/botao-excluir-cor.png">
        <input type="hidden" title="38" value="38" name="array_variacao[]">
    </li>
    <li>
        39
        <img class="botao-remover-tamanho" title="Remover cor" alt="" src="/admin/imagens/botao-excluir-cor.png">
        <input type="hidden" title="39" value="39" name="array_variacao[]">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**

By @Blender suggestion in the comments, i used the code in bellow post and it works fine to me.

[What is the easiest way to order a <UL>/<OL> in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery)

Comment: Try implementing the solution outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery

Comment: And One more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215341/order-sort-li-list-with-numeric-content-using-jquery/10215438#10215438

Comment: @Blender, Your suggestion works to me! Using the code in this question i got what was needing! Thank you!

Comment: @Vega, Thanks for your help! Using your code with and the answer i've putted in my last edit i got what i was needing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code,

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var liContents = [];
        $('ul li').each(function() {
            liContents.push($(this).html());
        });
        liContents.sort(liSorter);
        $('ul li').each(function() {
            $(this).html(liContents.pop());
        });
    });
});

/*
  Below function is kind of a workaround for the listed HTMl
  you need to update it if you have proper HTML.
*/
function liSorter(a, b) {
    return (parseInt(b) - parseInt(a));
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/9xwSV/6/)

**Edit:** Updated your markup a little for a better code,

1. Wrapped those number with `span` tags like `<span class="num">39</span>`
2. Updated sorter function as below,

**Code:**

```
function numOrdDesc(a, b) {
    var aTxt = parseInt($(a).find('.num').text(), 10);
    var bTxt = parseInt($(b).find('.num').text(), 10);
    return (bTxt - aTxt);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/9xwSV/8/)

Comment: Your code is nice and works! But for my case the suggestion that Blender gaves works better, it is more simple. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like this.

```
function numOrdDesc(a, b) {
    var aTxt = parseInt($(a)[0].innerText, 10);
    var bTxt = parseInt($(b)[0].innerText, 10);
    return (bTxt - aTxt);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9xwSV/486/)