# Sort Input Values in a Custom Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have multiple radio buttons with different values. I would like to sort these buttons according to the `value` or `id` in this order:

1. FedEx Ground
2. UPS Ground
3. Custom 1
4. Custom 2

Since the classes and names are the same for all options, the values, and ID's differ. I've tried using JavaScript but besides using ascending, descending, and random sort, I cannot figure out how to sort the options in a custom order by value.

```
<ul id="shipping_method">
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_1" value="booster_custom_shipping_1" class="shipping_method" checked="checked">
  <label for="shipping_method_custom_shipping_1">Custom 1:</label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_2" value="booster_custom_shipping_2" class="shipping_method">
  <label for="shipping_method_custom_shipping_2">Custom 2:</label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_3" value="FedEx - FedEx Ground" class="shipping_method">
  <label for="shipping_method_fedex_ground">FedEx Ground:</label>
 </li>
 <li>
   <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_4" value="UPS - UPS Ground" class="shipping_method">
   <label for="shipping_method_ups-ground">UPS Ground:</label>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, it's a custom order, so why would you think that numeric values or string sorts would work?

Comment: You want the actual buttons displayed in your custom sort order?

Comment: Duplicated? [Sort HTML list with HTML content using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288576/sort-html-list-with-html-content-using-jquery)

Comment: No, i wouldn't want the buttons displayed.

Comment: I'm assuming you're dynamically generating these `input`s, yes? If so, where are the values coming from? If not, reorder them in your HTML however you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an ordering object, look up the value in there, and sort based on that:

```js
var ordering = {
  "FedEx - FedEx Ground":      1,
  "UPS - UPS Ground":          2,
  "booster_custom_shipping_1": 3,
  "booster_custom_shipping_2": 4
};

$('#shipping_method > li').
  sort(
    function(a, b) {
      // for each <li>, get the value of the <input> it contains
      // look up that value in `ordering`, and use that for comparison
      //
      return ordering[ $('input', a).val() ] - ordering[ $('input', b).val() ];
    }
  ).
  each(
    // appending each element in sorted order leaves a sorted list behind
    //
    function() {
      $('#shipping_method').append(this);
    }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="shipping_method">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_1" value="booster_custom_shipping_1" class="shipping_method" checked="checked">
    <label for="shipping_method_custom_shipping_1">Custom 1:</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_2" value="booster_custom_shipping_2" class="shipping_method">
    <label for="shipping_method_custom_shipping_2">Custom 2:</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_3" value="FedEx - FedEx Ground" class="shipping_method">
    <label for="shipping_method_fedex_ground">FedEx Ground:</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_4" value="UPS - UPS Ground" class="shipping_method">
    <label for="shipping_method_ups-ground">UPS Ground:</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is absolutely beautiful. Works like a charm. I now understand the approach. I added the script to the `$(document).ready(function()`. Thanks a million Paul!

Answer (score 0):

A custom sort function would work... for example:

```
.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.value === b.value)
        return 0;

    switch(a.value) {
        case 'FedEx - FedEx Ground':
            return -1;
        case 'UPS - UPS Ground':
            if(b.value === 'FedEx - FedEx Ground')
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
        case 'booster_custom_shipping_1':
            if(b.value === 'FedEx - FedEx Ground' || b.value === 'UPS - UPS Ground')
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
        default:
            return 1;
    }
});
```