# Sorting by using css or jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

In section one, I have the HTML code of row records. If I want to write javascript or jquery to reorganize the HTML code to have the sorting effect on the row record by title, is it possible?
I want to sort below records by label title if I have the HTML that generated dynamically. Is it possible??

Section one

```
   <div id="listOfRecords">
        <div class="search list">
            <div class="row">
               <label id="title">FGH item</label>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label id="title">ABC item</label>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="search list">
             <div class="row">
                 <label id="title">CDE item</label>
             </div>
         </div>
    ...................
    </div>
```

Section two: Expected Result

```
<div id="listOfRecords">
    <div class="search list">
        <div class="row">
            <label id="title">ABC item</label>
         </div>
..................
         <div class="row">
             <label id="title">CDE item</label>
         </div>
.....................
         <div class="row">
           <label id="title">FGH item</label>
        </div>
....................
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try or search for something ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288576/sort-html-list-with-html-content-using-jquery . You can solve with JQuery plugins likehttp://listjs.com/ . Learn More about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort HTML list with HTML content using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288576/sort-html-list-with-html-content-using-jquery)

Comment: if your question is "Is it possible??" then the answer is "YES, it's possible!"