# How can I order a "ul" by "li" value?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have a button "Sort by" and it has "Price Low to High" and "Price High to Low". This button will order a list with my elements, on this case, properties! Is there a way to do that? Order a list by li value, not mattering what i have inside my tags?

```
<ul id="list">
 <li value="20">doesnmatter1</li>
 <li value="10">doesntmatter2</li>
 <li value="5">doesntmatter3</li>
 <li value="30">doesntmatter4</li>
 <li value="519">doesntmatter5</li>
```

```
$(function() {
            $('#ordena-menor').click(function() {
                var liContents = [];
                $('ul li').each(function() {
                    liContents.push(parseInt($(this).attr('value'), 10));
                });
                liContents.sort(numOrdDesc);
                $('ul li').each(function() {
                    $(this).text(liContents.pop());
                });
            });

            $('#ordena-maior').click(function() {
                var liContents = [];
                $('ul li').each(function() {
                    liContents.push(parseInt($(this).attr('value'), 10));
                });
                liContents.sort(numOrdCres);
                $('ul li').each(function() {
                    $(this).text(liContents.pop());
                });
            });
        });

        function numOrdDesc(a, b) {
            return (b - a);
        }

        function numOrdCres(a, b) {
            return (a - b);
        }
```

Check my demo -> [MYDEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s10d14vh/)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215341/how-to-order-sort-a-li-list-with-numeric-content-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use jquery:

```
var $list = $('ul'),
var $list_items = $list.children('li');
$list_items.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.attr('value') - b.attr('value');
});
$list_items.detach().appendTo($list);
```

You'll probably want to add an id to the `ul` element (and adjust the jquery selector accordingly) so that you don't end up accidentally sorting things you don't want to.