# How to sort multiple tables with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, encoding

I want to sort all values but jquery sorts only three values
I want multiple table sort on  tag h2 but  when i sort it only sort first 3 values but i want all values

```js
$('#alphBnt').on('click', function() {
  var sorting = $(".box").sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find("h2").text() > $(b).find("h2").text();
  });

  $("#container").html(sorting)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><button id="alphBnt">Sort</button></p>
<div id="container">
  <table border=2px class="box">

    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <h1>mui</h1>
      </td>
      <td class="number">
        <h2>4512</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border=2px class="box">

    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <h1>oinecellars</h1>
      </td>
      <td class="number">
        <h2>566</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border=2px class="box">

    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <h1>zacchus </h1>
      </td>
      <td class="number">
        <h2>34566</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border=2px class="box">

    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <h1>zacchus </h1>
      </td>
      <td class="number">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  


</div>
```

Comment: I added a dot `$("#container").html(sorting)` and added jQuery. Please add CSS so we can see what you mean by grey

Comment: Where is the outer table? Also `</table></table>` is invalid markup

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a ***[mcve]*** of your attempt, noting input and expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's a numeric sort

Comment: @mplungjan Did you event look for a dupe? Many of the answers on that dupe will work fine. But if we're going to be picky and not search because we answered the question, [How to order (sort) a <li> list with numeric content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10215341/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey it was not obvious from the initial code so I did not look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `-` :

```js
$('#alphBnt').on('click', function() {
  var sorting = $(".box").sort((a, b) => $(a).find("h2").text() - $(b).find("h2").text()).appendTo("#container")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><button id="alphBnt">Sort</button></p>
<div id="container">
  <table border=2px class="box">

    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <h1>mui</h1>
      </td>
      <td class="number">
        <h2>4512</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border=2px class="box">

    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <h1>oinecellars</h1>
      </td>
      <td class="number">
        <h2>566</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border=2px class="box">

    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <h1>zacchus </h1>
      </td>
      <td class="number">
        <h2>34566</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border=2px class="box">

    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <h1>zacchus </h1>
      </td>
      <td class="number">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>



</div>
```

Comment: thank you. it works